# Save or update record when two dirty forms are based on same recordsource

Tags: ms-access

There are two forms based on a single table named project. Form f_project shows the main project data and form f_phases shows the phase dates.

When a user updates information I need to update the fields edited_by and edit_date.

Form f_project has its Before Update event:

```
    Me!edit_date = Now
    Me!edited_by = TempVars!email
```

Form f_phases has the same. Note that the referenced fields are the exact same table fields.

The problem arises when one form is dirty and the other form tries to run its Before Update event.

You cannot use:

```
If Forms!f_project.Dirty Then Forms!f_project.Dirty = False
```

within the Before Update event of the form f_phases (and vice versa). I assume this is because they both have the same recordsource.

Attempting to change f_project's fields from f_phases results in a write conflict because you are also changing the same record within f_phases.

So, what I am trying to do in the end is detect whether the form f_project is dirty and save it prior to the record update made by form f_phases.

Any elegant solutions or workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

The (inelegant) way that I handled this issue is:

1. Made form f_phases modal so I only have to worry about whether form f_project is dirty.
2. Added the following code to form f_phases' Before Update event.

   ```
   If Application.SysCmd(acSysCmdGetObjectState, acForm, "f_project") = acObjStateOpen Then
      If Forms!f_project.Dirty = False Then
          Me!edit_date = Now
          Me!edited_by = TempVars!email
      End If
   Else
      Me!edit_date = Now
      Me!edited_by = TempVars!email
   End If
   ```

Basically what it does is if form f_project is either not open or is not dirty it will update the last edit information. If f_project is dirty it simply does nothing. It allows f_project to handle the last edit update.